# nginx rewrite multiple arguments

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite

1. `web.com/ab` to `web.com?sys=ab`
2. `web.com/ab/cd` to `web.com?sys=ab&id=cd`
3. `web.com` is unchanged.

I've written the following:

```
rewrite ^/(\w+)(/?\w*)$ /?system=$1&id=$2 break;
```

Comment: I cannot make this fail. Do you clear the browser's cache between tests? A stale cache can cause unpredictable results.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, of course. I tested writing `?system=test&id=5` it worked, but `/test/5` doesn't

Comment: @RichardSmith It tries to find my js/css files in `/test/` when I access `/test/5`!   `Unable to find web.com/test/user.css`. Rewriting is incorrect..

Comment: That is a different problem. If you use path-relative URIs for resource files **and** use routes that "look-like" sub-directories, the browser is going to request the resource file by prefixing the apparent sub-directory. You need to use path-absolute resource files with this kind of scheme.

Comment: @RichardSmith But if the URL is rewritten, browser should see `?system=2&id=5`, not subdirectory...

Comment: No. Browser sees what is written in the *address bar*. If you want the browser to see your rewritten URL you need to use a redirect (like your last rewrite statement) - in which case the *address bar* will necessarily change. At the moment, you are only changing the URL within `nginx`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks. So, If I want the URL to be in this way, I can't use relative path for js/css? No way?

Comment: You could try using an HTML `base` tag, but it may just add a whole lot of new problems. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag) for details.

Comment: Great! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your rewrite statement, I get:

1. `web.com/ab` to `web.com?sys=ab&id=`
2. `web.com/ab/cd` to `web.com?sys=ab&id=/cd`
3. `web.com` is unchanged.

You can fix (2) by moving the parentheses so that the second `/` is not captured. The simplest way to fix (1) is to replace your one `rewrite` statement with two:

```
rewrite ^/(\w+)/(\w*)$ /?system=$1&id=$2 break;
rewrite ^/(\w+)$       /?system=$1       break;
```

Comment: It works for 1 parameter, however doesn't work for 2.

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps there is something else in your configuration that is causing you problems.

Comment: Updated the question, added actual data

Comment: BTW how do you test the statements?

Comment: I paste the configuration into my test server which is running `nginx/1.10.1`